# :nth-child and infinite scroll

Tags: html, css, infinite-scroll, css-selectors

On a [site I'm creating](http://reggi.myshopify.com/collections/all#) we have a grid of items and all the rows float properly because of this little snippet of CSS:

`.collection .grid-item:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: left;
}`

Which makes the first item in each row `clear:left`, this allows for the new row to begin where the height of the tallest row ends.

This works perfectly.

However when I try to add infinite scroll it's breaking the grid. Infinite scroll is adding two items `display:none` items to the grid, the pagination, and the loading bar.

For some reason the css for `clear:left` is recognizing these two elements and creating two gaps in the grid on every page loaded to the grid.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I had this exact same problem.  I had to use jQuery to count the 'visible' items and then add a class to every 4 one in that count to clear it.  Here's the question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557240/visible-not-working-with-nth-child-selector and the solution gilly3 gave me: http://jsbin.com/OVewUkaM/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nth-child` will treat each of the child elements of `.grid-item` equally, and so your pagination and loading bar qualify. Try moving your pager and loader outside of .grid-item.

Comment: I didn't realize it selected the children within that selector. `.grid-item` is the selector for the items within the grid I want to select on an individual basis. What if I can't move those items?? Is there any way to just select those items??? Ignoring the ones I don't want to incorporate.

Comment: It won't select items that don't match `.grid-item` and so the style won't be applied to those items. However, those items still affect the _index_ of the items around it (it doesn't just scope items that match the selector for indexing).