# :visible not working with :nth-child selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of items in a grid.  Some of them are hidden with CSS using `display: none;` via a class `.hide`.

I'm trying to 'clear' every 4th **visible** item by adding a class `.clear-left` to it.  I can't understand why my script doesn't work.  I'm using the :visible selector but it seems to still be counting items that are `display: none;`.

What should happen is that you should always see 3 items on a row and no gaps.

**http://jsbin.com/ipORemIs/1/edit**

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item hide">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item hide">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

/* Items that are hidden */
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.clear-left {
  clear: left;
}
```

JS

```
var $itemShow = $('.item:visible');

$itemShow.filter(':nth-child(3n+1)').addClass('clear-left');
```

Comment: nth-child selector will not work based on custom index... it works based on the index based on sibling elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get this with pure CSS, so change your filter to a function that checks to see if the index of the item is divisible by 3:

```
$itemShow.filter(function(i){ return i % 3 === 0; }).addClass('clear-left');
```

http://jsbin.com/OVewUkaM/1/edit

This uses the Modulus operator.  It gives you the remainder when dividing two numbers.

```
0 % 3;  // 0
1 % 3;  // 1
2 % 3;  // 2
3 % 3;  // 0
4 % 3;  // 1
5 % 3;  // 2
6 % 3;  // 0
```

**Edit:** But I prefer to do this sort of thing with pure CSS by limiting the width of the container.

```css
.grid {
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 606px
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oXeGeGus/2/edit

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!  Could you just explain about `=== 0`?  I understand that `i % 3` is saying if the index is divisible by 3, but what does that `=== 0` part mean?

Comment: Yeah I agree on the CSS thing, but when the items vary in height and you don't want to set a min-height, you run into issues with the layout of the floats.

Comment: @davidpauljunior - Good point about min height.  See my edit for an explanation of the modulus operator.

Comment: Just seen your edit with the modulus operator remainder list.  Very clear and very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) selector will not work based on custom index... it works based on the index based on sibling elements, so you have to implement the filtering yourself like

```
var $itemShow = $('.item:visible');

$itemShow.filter(function(idx){
    return idx % 4 == 3;//because index starts with 0
}).addClass('clear-left');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sxA4J/)

Comment: Can you explain briefly what `idx % 4 == 3;` means?  In Layman's terms? I have read that % means 'Modulus (division remainder)' but that means nothing to me.  I do understand that `== 3` is the 4th item, just not sure exaclty what `idx % 4` means.

Comment: @davidpauljunior it is the [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) operator... it gives the reminder of an division operation like `3 % 4` = gives, `4 % 4 = 0`, `5 % 4 = 1` ... etc

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child` only applies to the node name, not any other classes or psuedo-classes or anything else that has also been applied.

You will have to iterate through all visible items, and apply your class only if `i%4==3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it in my code, where I needed to display a div after every 5 visible divs of the class "cities":

```
var $itemShow = $('.cities:visible');
$itemShow.filter(function(i){ return (i+1) % 5 == 0; }).after(function(){return "<div>Reminded that I needed to put after every 5 divs of the class 'cities' or after the last 'cities' div if the total of divs of the class 'cities' is less than 5.</div>";});
```

`i+1` because the index of the first element is zero.

In my case, if the number of divs of the class "cities" is less than 5, I also wanted to show the reminder, so I added this code as well:

```
if($('.cities:visible').length < 5){
    $('.cities:visible').last().after("<div>Reminded that I needed to put after every 5 divs of the class 'cities' or after the last 'cities' div if the total of divs of the class 'cities' is less than 5.</div>");
}
```